# Forward local PC packets through local pc connected to a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables

I have this situation:

**My target:** connect to FTP port of a local PC in my house from the external.

**What i have:** a home-server connected to a VPN (which I can access) and a dedicated server with a public ip that host the VPN.

I want to transfer some files on one of many of my PC I have at home, and I would do it via FTP, or I would simply arrive to port 80 of that PC.

I tried to do port forwarding on my router, also putting a Dynamic DNS, but my network manager has the address of my router under NAT. Therefore, I can not access from the outside.

Initially I tried Hamachi as a solution, or by creating a mesh network with all pc connected to the same network, but it was no good because he had problems.

So I set up a VPN on a server with a public address, only problem: I can connect only ONE PC in my home (that i called Home Server or, shortened, HS). With the PC in my workstation I can connect to the VPN, and can connect to the HS.

Now my goal, it's switch the traffic that is on port 21 of the pc I call PC1, to the port 100 of HS, in this way I could reach ftp PC1 through port 100 HS.

There is a way to do this with iptables maybe? Because HS runs linux.

To those who are not yet clear the situation:

[Explanation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj13C.png)

Comment: Why are you only able to connect to one using the VPN?

Comment: PC1, or other local machines are not able to connect via VPN. Yes, it sounds strange, but unfortunately it is so. Think of PC1 as if it was not a real computer but as a normal device that connects to a local network (For example a local cloud storage) @Seth

Comment: Did you check if your router would support being that VPN endpoint? You'd have to setup a NAT on your HS to do that kind of address translation an example could be [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/586486/how-to-do-the-port-forwarding-from-one-ip-to-another-ip-in-same-network) or [this blog](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/).

Comment: My router does not support to be a VPN endpoint, but your [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/586486/how-to-do-the-port-forwarding-from-one-ip-to-another-ip-in-same-network) could be the answer, now I'm trying. @Seth